# Moderators to delete duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, moderators, duplicate-answers

A moderator or trusted user should be given right to straight away delete duplicate questions with answers that won't change over time, as they would already have enough experience to understand which questions differ from each other. The user can then be given option to edit the question or remove it if he thinks its duplicate too.

Comment: Why is it so important that duplicates be deleted immediately (or at all, for that matter)? We believe that duplicates server a useful role in that different searches will find different questions - having a link to the duplicate is a good thing.

Comment: See [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: duplicate as in same question with a change in the terms used and similar things. Duplicate doesnt mean question on the same topic.

Comment: @prince Can you provide some examples? I'm not really understanding what you're trying to say in your latest comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators already have the ability to do this as well as merge duplicate questions, although it is never really necessary. Trusted users **should not** have this ability, usually duplicate questions serve as signposts which direct users to a canonical answer. We shouldn't be promoting their deletion by suddenly allowing trusted users to delete them.

Also keep in mind that sometimes people answer duplicate questions many years after the original with more up to date code, which we have to account for.